# Windows 8 rear camera

Tags: c#, windows, camera, windows-store-apps

So I've done some googling and can't really find any answer to this. I have an windows store application that is using the MediaCapture API, what i can't find is a way to find if the device has a rear camera and switch to that. Is there any samples or anybody got any ups on how this can be accomplished.
Thanks
Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I have come it with an answer by playing around!

If you use `DeviceInfomation.FindAllAsync` to look for video capture devices you can get the enclosure location and then loop through until you find one that corresponds to `Back`.

Then you can get the `ID` of the element and set it into your camera `id` using `MediaCaptureInitalizationSettings` then all you have to do is initialize with the settings and hey presto!.